# Length validation on Rails - which one is the best?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am coding the validation of my app and want to know if there's any difference (security and/or speed) between the use of
`length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 30 }` and `length: 5..30`, for example.

Sorry if this had already been asked...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no difference in performance because they mean the same thing. The range syntax

```
length: 5..30
```

is simply shorthand for an array containing the numbers 5 through 30

```
length: [5,6,7,...30].to_a
```

You can also use the minimum and maximum attributes to declare a range.

```
length: { minimum: 5, maximum: 30 }
```

Check out the documentation here

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#length

> :minimum - The attribute cannot have less than the specified length.
>
> :in (or :within) - The attribute length must be included in a given interval. The value for this option must be a range.

It comes down to preference. The range syntax saves you keystrokes. But there's no difference in performance. You can see for yourself with `benchmark`.

Comment: You need to edit your wording as it seems like you are saying ranges are arrays, which of course they are not. `Array` and `Range` have different methods and arrays require memory for all of its elements, whereas only the endpoints are stored for ranges. Moreover, not all ranges can be converted to arrays, `(1.2)..(3.4)` being an example.

Comment: Ranges have two or three dots between them, not one. But yeah, I will try to edit the wording. Thanks